# ObjectInputStream read Array

Tags: java, servlets, objectinputstream

I am trying to read in an array from ObjectInputStream in Java.  I can find no documentation on how to do this.  I assume that it is readObject(), but this doesn't seem to work.

```
out.write(Object)
out.write(Object)
out.write(boolean[])
```

... in servlet ...

```
Object one = in.readObject();
Object two = in.readObject();
boolean[] thr = (boolean[])in.readObject();
```

Is this correct or am I doing it wrong?  If it's correct then any ideas on why it might not like this?

Comment: When you say it doesn't seem to work, does it throw an exception? Can you give some more detail on exactly what is going wrong?

Comment: take note.  This question is not answerable without more details.

Comment: Define 'doesn't seem to work'. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reading code is correct. Your writing pseudo-code is also correct, assuming that it really is pseudo-code and that you are actually calling those methods with arguments of those types in that order.

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing.  I think my problem is lying elsewhere, but I wanted to make sure that readObject() was the right thing to use.  Wish me luck..